# Python : Plotly - Parallel Coordinates - Color of unmarked lines

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, parallel-coordinates

I have the following question. I am using plotlys parallel coordinates and I need the unmarked lines to appear in another color than the standard gray as it is as default. Is there any option to do that?

Best regards[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUCcF.jpg)

Comment: According to https://plot.ly/python/reference/#parcoords you should probably use `colorscale`, and give it a dict of values you want to use there.

Answer (score -1):

You can try someting like that

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
data = [
    go.Parcoords(
        marker = dict(
            size = 10,
            color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)', # default
            line = dict(
                width = 2,
                color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
            )
        )
    )
]
```

Comment: I get the error : PlotlyDictKeyError: 'marker' is not allowed in 'parcoords'

Path To Error: ['marker']

Valid attributes for 'parcoords' at path [] under parents []:

    ['customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dimensions', 'domain', 'hoverinfo',
    'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'labelfont',
    'legendgroup', 'line', 'name', 'opacity', 'rangefont',
    'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'stream', 'tickfont', 'type', 'uid',
    'visible']